# How do I work with dates like 201601191204?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have the date `201601191204` in a text file.

How do I change `201601191204` to this `2016-01-19 12:04` with php?

It is not unix time, what is it?

Comment: This question has been asked number of times.. Did you search Google?

Comment: Yes but just do not know where I should look for

Comment: echo date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime('201601191204'));

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public string DateTime::format ( string $format )

public string DateTimeImmutable::format ( string $format )

public string DateTimeInterface::format ( string $format )
```